# how to sum values for same ocurrence in a file?

Tags: perl, unix, average

I have the next csv file :

```
id;nucleotides
seq1;230
seq2;40
seq1;50
seq3;30
```

and the desire result is the unique id and the sum of the nucleotides :

```
id;nucleotides
seq1;280
seq2;40
seq3;30
```

Is there any fast way to do it in Perl or unix?

Comment: What did you try? What issues are you having?

Comment: `$counts{$row->{id}} += $row->{nucleotides};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my %count;

while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        next if $. == 1; # skip header
        my ($id, $nuc) = split(/;/, $_);
        $count{$id} += $nuc;
}

if (scalar (keys ( %count ) ) > 0) {
        say "id;nucleotides";
        foreach (sort keys %count) {
                say "$_;$count{$_}";
        }
}

__DATA__
id;nucleotides
seq1;230
seq2;40
seq1;50
seq3;30
```

Comment: Your `if (! $hash{$id}) ... else ...` should just be `$hash{$id} += $nuc`. Also, (as @Borodin will surely mention soon), `%hash` is not a good name for a hash.

Comment: Tip: `if (scalar (keys ( %count ) ) > 0)` can be written `if (%count)`

Comment: Tip: The first `say` should be outside the `if` (making the `if` useless).

Answer (score 2):

**awk:**

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1;(NR>1){A[$1]+=$2} END{for(i in A)print i";"A[i]}' file
```

1) `-F';'` - `;` char as separator

2)  `NR==1;` - print the first line (title)

3) `(NR>1){A[$1]+=$2}` - if not the first line, sum the value to $1 hash (a) key

4) `END{for(i in A)print i";"A[i]` - once finished sum of all file's lines print hash in "key;value" format